# Reference request: Lower group (co)homology of linear groups

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology, linear-groups, group-homology

I am finding references about the following general question:

> What is the group (co)homology $H_{i}(G,\mathbb{Z})$ for a linear group $G$?

In my case, I'm particularly interested in the special case where $G = \mathrm{PGL}(n,F)$ is the projective linear group, and $F$ is the complex field $\mathbb{C}$ or some function field over $\mathbb{C}$. From what I've heard such computation was done for $i \leq 3$. Where can I find the reference for such results?